# Vim: Restrict the number of candidates provided by spell

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How can I restrict the number of candidate words provided by `spell`? The native behavior is to populate the entire screen with candidate words, sorted by the degree of relevance. Usually, only the 10 first candidates are reasonably close. Populating the entire screen (which for my case would be 109 lines) is unnecessary, is not pointless.

Any suggestion to suppress the number of candidates provided by `spell`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:set spellsuggest=best,10` to limit the spelling suggestions list to 10 words.

Note that there are multiple possible strategies for filling the suggestion list (`best` being the default). See `:help spellsuggest` for more informations.